# Alternative for deprecated PHP function: eregi_replace

Tags: php, function, deprecated

Do anyone know a good alternative for the deprecated eregi_replace function?

I need it for this sniplet:

```
$pattern = "([a-z0-9][_a-z0-9.-]+@([0-9a-z][_0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6})";
$replace = "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\">\\1</a>";
$text = eregi_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**preg_replace**

https://php.net/preg-replace

```
$pattern = "/([a-z0-9][_a-z0-9.-]+@([0-9a-z][_0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6})/i";
$replace = "<a href=\"mailto:\\1\">\\1</a>";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $text);
```

Comment: You need to use delimiter characters for `preg_XXX()`. Since the OP is looking for an alternative to `eregi` (case-insensitive), you should also add the `i` flag (`preg_replace('/(...)/i', ...)`).

Comment: True, bad copy/paste, sorry about that, I added it to my answer

Comment: For substitution I believe the \\1 needs to be updated to be $1

Answer (score 1):

[preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace)