# Deprecated: Function eregi_replace()

Tags: php, function, replace, deprecated, eregi

I am getting the following error when running on PHP 5.3.8

> Deprecated: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in
>   /home/XXXXXX/public_html/admin/modifypoll.php on line 49

This is the line of code, can anyone help please

```
$question = eregi_replace('</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>', '', $question );
```

I am not sure what to change it to.
Can anyone help please

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative for Deprecated PHP Function eregi_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084881/alternative-for-deprecated-php-function-eregi-replace)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the entire ereg family of functions are deprecated in PHP and will at some point be removed from the language. The replacement is the preg family. For the most part, the change is simple:

```
preg_replace('/[^<>]>/i', '', $question);
^--           ^      ^^
```

1. change ereg to preg
2. add delimeters (`/`)
3. for case insensitive matches (ereg`i`), add the `i` modifier

Comment: You need to update the regex, too - when copying it from the original question it was broken due to lack of code formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try and keep this safe for next time

Answer (score 1):

```
$question = preg_replace('/<\/?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>/i', '', $question);
```

By the way, you can simply use `$question = strip_tags($question);` to achieve the same without any regexes!