# eregi_replace deprecated

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deprecated: Function eregi_replace()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679656/deprecated-function-eregi-replace)

I have an error that reads:

> Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /home/socia125/public_html/wi_class_files/autoMakeLinks.php on line 26

My code is here. Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

    class autoActiveLink {

    function makeActiveLink($originalString){

        $newString = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a 

        href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $originalString);
        return $newString;
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$newString = preg_replace("#[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]#","<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $originalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ereg` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use **[`preg`](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** instead.

```
class autoActiveLink {
    function makeActiveLink($originalString) {

        $newString = preg_replace("|[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]|",
                                  "<a href=\"\\0\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>",
                                  $originalString
        );
        return $newString;
    }
}
```

Note that on `preg` functions, you need a delimiter for your Regex. Refer to the **[manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** for additional details.

Comment: yes i am having a hard time understanding in which form to use them i appreciate your reply

Comment: @RockoJedi: On most cases, simply replace the `e` of ereg with `p`, and that should do the trick.

Comment: You missed the delimiter for the pattern.

Comment: @Truth you need to put pattern separators around the pattern in the string too (you did not in your example).

Comment: @bsdnoobz: Correct, corrected!

Comment: now i am receiving this error Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '+' in /home/socia125/public_html/wi_class_files/autoMakeLinks.php on line 28
@Truth

Comment: @RockoJedi: Are you trying to match a URL? Use this pattern `/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/` (taken from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/find-urls-in-text-make-links/))

Answer (score 0):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg-replace) instead.

For the most part, the only real difference is that you have to have delimiters around the regex. I usually use `(` at the start and `)` at the end, but you can use any two matching symbols. The advantage of `()` is that you never have to escape anything just for the purpose of avoiding conflict with the delimiter.